# How to make logdata as Kibana graph value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am having a log file that gives  a **Duration : 10** with timestamp in my logfile. When i a put a search field in kibana for duration, i am able to get a point coming in the graph whenever duration is coming in the log file. How can i get/set the value of a point at the graph.

currently

```
10:12:34 Duration :5
10:17:19 Duration :7
```

Whenever Duration is coming a point is coming in the graph.How to set the value at the particular timestamp to 7/10 or whtever is corresponding value for duration.

my logstash conf file is as follows

```
input {

 file {

   path => "C:/log.txt"    

    }

}

 filter {
  extractnumbers {
  add_field => [ "Duration", "%{message}" ]
 }
}

output {

 stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
elasticsearch { 
 embedded => true 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was able to fetch the data of type duration.I added the following filter in **logstash.conf** file. We can replace Duration with any field we want to extract.

```
filter {
  extractnumbers {
  add_field => [ "Duration", "%{message}" ]
}
}
```

In the kibana dash board we can extract corresponding values.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this:

```
grok {
   match => ["message", %{TIME:time}.*%{NUMBER:duration}]
}

date { match => [ "time", "HH:mm:ss" ] }
```